# Object persistence without ORM or DB Engine

Tags: linq, nosql, persistence

I learned to love how LINQ enables set operations on collections. I'm not saying that I plan to shun traditional RDMBS, because I do need it for reporting. There are NoSQL alternatives out there, but they seem to all need to fire up a separate service.

What I looking for is something local where a DLL can create a database and perform CRUD on it. As mentioned, I'm not going to report out of this, just internal data store. The main application that will be using it is in C#.

I'm hoping that someone can give me a lead. If not, if there is anyone willing, we can start a open-source project for it. I'm not interested in commercial products.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, we can serialize to a file. But this is still a collection of objects. It will be beneficial to be able to lazy load selected objects.

Comment: You can run [RavenDB in embedded mode](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/embedded) inside your .NET application - no need for external services or anything. And RavenDB supports Linq ....

Comment: Thanks,Now, how do I mark this thing as answered?

Comment: It helps to notify @marc_s by using the "@". He will probably convert his comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run [RavenDB in embedded mode](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/embedded) inside your .NET application - no need for external services or anything.

And RavenDB supports Linq....